# Orion in Docker can not communicate with accumulator-server: Notification failure for localhost

Tags: fiware-orion

I am using `docker-compose` to run Orion+Mongo.

Then, I am starting `accumulator-server` with:

```
drasko@Lenin:~/fiware/fiware-orion/scripts$ ./accumulator-server.py 1028 /accumulate on
verbose mode is on
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:1028/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However, running a gives an error:

```
orion_1 | WARNING@21:27:21  httpRequestSend.cpp[438]: Notification failure for localhost:1028 (curl_easy_perform failed: Couldn't connect to server)
```

Could it be due the fact that Orion is run in the Docker and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you edit your question post to include the subscription that you are using, please? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "subscription I am using"? I am running `docker-compose` for the Orion, and running `accumulator-server.py` in another terminal.

Comment: Just after installing Orion, its DB starts empty. Thus, in order to make Orion sending notification you have needed to create a subscritption (typically using `POST /v1/subscribeContext` operation).

Comment: I am trying to make a subscription off course - and this is what is not working. As I mention - it looks that Orion inside a Docker can not reach accumulator app run on the localhost. Can you please try on your side and confirm this?

Comment: I think that @LeandroGuillen answer describes the solution to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your Orion host cannot reach the accumulator.

In the subscription you are using a reference field with the value "localhost", so Orion is looking in its localhost relative to the docker container.

To solve it, you should either run the accumulator inside the docker image or make Orion able to contact the accumulator in some other way than "localhost" (maybe run accumulator in a different container and link it using docker compose).

Comment: Indeed, I had to put `"reference": "http://192.168.0.46:1028/accumulate"` to Context Subscription JSON, which is my PC host ip address. This way Orion in Docker (which had an ip addr 172.17.0.48) could send request to `accumulator-server` on my PC host.